# How to change user id from incremental integer to random hash?

Tags: 7, users

By default drupal uses incremental user id but I want random 7 character hash, is there any module that can help me with that? If not what is the simplest way to achieve that?

from:
    user/1

to:
    user/5rey2t5

by the way I know how to generate the hash in php I'm looking for the best way to implement it.

Comment: to paraphrase @molot from another question, but this appears to be an XY problem, where you are asking about X to solve Y.  So perhaps if you could shed some more light on WHY you are trying to do this, a (perhaps better) answer may present itself.

Comment: I don't want to be visible who is the first user and who is second.

Comment: if that's the case, then you might want to look into some menu alters or permissions that don't allow your casual users to go to user/# unless they are looking at themselves.  otherwise, you are going to have to do a lot of modifications, the least of which would be to figure out how to deal with the fact that drupal assigns specific attributes in a hard coded fashion to uid 1 (and 0).  but you could certainly add another field to a user that is that hash and shadow the menu path, eg, users/HASH as an alias for user/#, etc, and hide the user/# path from them.

Comment: Do you want only in /user/uid this happen or in all of part instead userid show hash ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was already mentioned in comments, you can avoid such a harsh hack of drupal core by forbidding anyone to see the UIDs. The simplest solution that comes to my mind is module Pathauto (https://drupal.org/project/pathauto) which will easily translate all user/uid paths to whatever you want, usually user/username.

If you really require the hash, I believe it could be created as separate field when user is created (some logic would have to be implemented to avoid duplicates) and then used as token for pathauto automatic alias generation, but this approach seems rather silly to me.
Let me know if you want more elaborate guidelines on that.

Answer (score 3):

Just aliasing the path (as suggested by *m1n0*) will not be enough, as  users allowed to see the user profile will still be able to connect a user name and profile to a numeric user ID by entering an URL ending with `user/ID` (where `ID` is an integer, e.g. `1` for user #1). This will let anyone permitted to view user profiles to view the user name and profile associated with `user/ID`.

As pointed out by *Jimajamma*, totally replacing the numeric user ID with a random hash is a major undertaking, since just doing it will break a lot of stuff hard coded in Drupal.  No module exists that will do this for you.  If you want to do this, you'll have to start from scratch.

What you need to do to avoid numeric user IDs from being associated with specific user names and profiles is to prevent non-privileged users from ever seeing the *user profile*.

Navigate to  *Administration » People » Permission* and make sure that non-privileged user does *not* have the permission "View user profile".

After doing this, if a non-privileged user typed in an URL ending with `user/1` (or anURL with any other numeric user ID) a 403 status code (Permission denied) will be returned.  Also user names that appear in bylines, etc. will no longer be linked to a profile when viewed by a  non-privileged user.